# Instantiating interface implementation from another assembly the right way

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, interface, .net-assembly

I'm currently developing some kind of "mini SDK" with useful classes and functions I often use.

Therefore I made several interfaces which can be implemented in other assemblies.

So it basically looks like this:

```
// In SDK.dll:

namespace MySDK
{
    public interface IExample
    {
        /* .. */
    }   
}


// In another assembly:

namespace Example
{
    public class Implementation : MySDK.IExample
    {
        /* .. */
    }
}
```

This is no problem. My problem is, in the SDK I want to use the actual implementation of this interface, so what I've done is this:

```
// in SDK.dll

    private IExample GetImplementation(string fileName)
    {
        Type implementation = Assembly
            .LoadFrom(fileName)
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t =>
                t.GetInterface(typeof(IExample).FullName) != null
                && (t.Attributes & TypeAttributes.Abstract) != TypeAttributes.Abstract)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if(implementation != null)
        {
            return (IExample)Activator.CreateInstance(implementation);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works and does what I want it to do, but it looks really ugly and somehow wrong.

I'm not sure, is this the right / best way to do this or ***is there any better way?***

Comment: " in the SDK I want to use the actual implementation of this interface" why?  that seems backwards.  What if an app that uses _other_ interface does not define an implementation?  Seems like it would be better for the SDK to have a parameter or property where the other DLL could _pass in_ an implementation.

Comment: Well.. now that you say it I wonder why I didn't try this approach yet. I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the first part to that:

```
Type implementation = Assembly
        .LoadFrom(fileName)
        .GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => typeof(IExample).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But the bigger problem I see in your code is that it works only if the implementing class has a parameterless constructor. You should test for that, too.

Next problem would be generic types. So I suggest this:

```
Type implementation = Assembly
        .LoadFrom(fileName)
        .GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => 
            typeof(IExample).IsAssignableFrom(t) && 
            !t.IsAbstract &&
            !t.IsGenericType &&
            t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public).Any(c => !c.GetParameters().Any())
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But there maybe further problems in this approach.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was running into .. 
Anyway, I think what 'D Stanley' wrote as comment to the question is the actual answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, @DStanley is right. Think I'll leave this answer for reference.